# jquery multiple selection box value sharing

Tags: jquery

How do i get the value from multiple drop down for the below html and write a javascript.

```
<label for="select"></label>
<select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="1">p1-$10</option>
    <option value="2">p2-$20</option>
    <option value="3">p3-$30</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="a">$10-a</option>
    <option value="b">$20-b</option>
    <option value="c">$30-c</option>
</select>
```

Amount - $75.00 + Selection Option

I want amount 75.00 value to be change on drop down selection. pls help

Comment: Could you explain what you're looking for more clearly.  Do you just want some text that says Amount - $75.00 + (The value of the Selected option)?  You have multiple dropdowns in your example so are we adding both to the amount value?

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you can use `change()` events. I see in your selects, the values you have are letters, I would consider changing them to the numerical values of the actual select text, then you can do:

```
$("#select, #select2").change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

If you want to add them, you can do something like this:

```
var total = 0;
$("#select, #select2").change(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value);
    alert(total);
});
```

Comment: but my code is like this <script>
$("#basic4").change(function()
{       var basic4c = $("#basic4").val();
    if(basic4c == 'pay')
    {
        var pricec = "£0.00/ Month";
        $("#amount").val(pricec);
 // then display it in the following class
$(".display_text_herec").text(pricec);
    };
 }).change();

$("#basic3").change(function()
{       
var basic3bc = $("#basic3").val();
if(basic3bc == 'Beta')
{
var bprice = "£16.99/ Month";
$("#amount").val(bprice);
// then display it in the following class
$(".display_text_herebc").text(bprice);
};
    
}).change();
</script>

Answer (score 0):

here's my bid ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/TNvep/)):

```
// here's the $75 you referenced
var basePrice = 75.00;

// our calculate function (so it can be called on page load and when they change
// their selection from the drop-downs.
function calculate(){
    // begin tallying price
    var price = basePrice;
    // go through each select list
    $('select').each(function(){
        // grab the selected option's text, then try to extact the
        // price from within (e.g. look for "$xx.xx")
        var sel = $(':selected',this).text(),
            itemprice = parseFloat(sel.match(/\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1.2})?)/)[1], 10);
        price += itemprice;
        // add it to running total
    });
    // now display the result back on the page.
    $('#price').text(price.toFixed(2));
}
// when the select changes, recalculate
$('select').change(calculate);
// also calculate when the page loads.
calculate();
```

---

Addendum: I would recommend that instead of trying to grab the price from within the item's text you use either the `value=""` field (if you can, though it may reference a database id to that item), otherwise, use the [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.dataset). an example of this would be...

a couple of changes to your items (e.g.)

```
<option value="1" data-price="10.00">p1-$10</option>
```

Then the change to the script:

```
//var sel = $(':selected',this).text(),
//        itemprice = parseFloat(sel.match(/\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1.2})?)/)[1], 10);
var itemprice = $(':selected',this).data('price');
```